Android Emulator gives "Aborted (core dumped)" when openning a game
i'm using an android emulator from android studio, the emulator crashes when i open a game i got from playstore, here are the details and the stack trace (resulted from running the emulator from the terminal with the -verbose flag)
Details;
Properties
avd.ini.displayname              Pixel 9 Pro XL API 35
avd.ini.encoding                 UTF-8
AvdId                            Pixel_9_Pro_XL_API_35
disk.dataPartition.size          10000M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile      
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot no
fastboot.forceColdBoot           no
fastboot.forceFastBoot           yes
hw.accelerometer                 yes
hw.arc                           false
hw.audioInput                    yes
hw.battery                       yes
hw.camera.back                   virtualscene
hw.camera.front                  emulated
hw.cpu.ncore                     4
hw.device.hash2                  MD5:df6942f9ab0ed0550ee98b91920f684e
hw.device.manufacturer           Google
hw.device.name                   pixel_9_pro_xl
hw.dPad                          no
hw.gps                           yes
hw.gpu.enabled                   yes
hw.gpu.mode                      auto
hw.initialOrientation            portrait
hw.keyboard                      yes
hw.lcd.density                   480
hw.lcd.height                    2992
hw.lcd.width                     1344
hw.mainKeys                      no
hw.ramSize                       2048
hw.sdCard                        yes
hw.sensors.orientation           yes
hw.sensors.proximity             yes
hw.trackBall                     no
image.androidVersion.api         35
image.sysdir.1                   system-images/android-35/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
PlayStore.enabled                true
runtime.network.latency          none
runtime.network.speed            full
showDeviceFrame                  yes
skin.dynamic                     yes
tag.display                      Google Play
tag.displaynames                 Google Play
tag.id                           google_apis_playstore
tag.ids                          google_apis_playstore
vm.heapSize                      256

here is the stack trace from when i started to load the game
I1113 21:47:03.575268  341892 VkDecoderGlobalState.cpp:1039] Created VkInstance:0x563757dc7000 for application:1v1.LOL engine:Unity.
I1113 21:47:03.597307  341892 VkDecoderGlobalState.cpp:1039] Created VkInstance:0x563757dc7000 for application:1v1.LOL engine:Unity.
I1113 21:47:03.644465  341892 VkDecoderGlobalState.cpp:1861] Created VkDevice:0x5637585ca050 for application:1v1.LOL engine:Unity ASTC emulation:on CPU decoding:off.
I1113 21:47:04.611171  341892 GpuDecompressionPipeline.cpp:183] Created GPU decompression pipeline for format VK_FORMAT_ETC2_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_BLOCK VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D. ASTC decoder: NewRgb
F1113 21:47:04.694971  341904 VkDecoderGlobalState.cpp:9653] FATAL in unbox_VkBuffer, err code: 4300000000: Unbox 0x1cdc0de failed, not found.
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.699984:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700508:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700538:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700574:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700604:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700651:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700679:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700707:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700737:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700784:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700842:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.700870:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.702181:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.702204:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.702209:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.702213:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.702217:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.702221:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.702225:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.702230:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733173:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733187:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733247:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733251:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733259:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733263:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733267:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733271:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733278:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733281:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733286:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733289:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733297:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733300:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733304:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
[340719:340719:20241113,214704.733307:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
Aborted (core dumped)

